# Probability of a 4-digit number with all its digits different being a multiple of 11?

Tags: probability

**What is the probability of a 4-digit number of the form abcd(a,b,c,d are all different) is a multiple of 11?**

```
(a) 0.1420
(b) 0.0480
(c) 0.0720
(d) 0.091
```

*Can it be assumed that the ratio of 4-digit numbers of the form abcd which are multiples of 11 to that of all 4-digit numbers of the form abcd is 1? If yes, then is this right?*

> (((9999-1001)/11) + 1) / ( 9999 - 999 )= 91/1000

**EDIT:** *This is what I intend to know*

> Is the proportion of the "all digits distinct" 4-digit numbers that
>   are divisible by 11 among all 4-digit numbers divisible by 11  equal
>   to the proportion "all digits distinct" 4-digit numbers among all
>   numbers from 1001 to 9999?

*Thanks to Andre Nicolas for stating this in his comment*

Comment: First question: obviously no. Second question: yes.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Please can you explain how it is solved? (That is not my solution)

Comment: Sure I could. You first: what did you do? (You might be aware that to explain what one did is part of the recommended modus operandi on the site.)

Comment: Yes. There are 819 multiples of 11 between 1001 and 9999. And the total number of 4-digit numbers are 9000. But I'm stuck at how to proceed with the digits being different though this gives the stated answer.

Comment: Would it help to know that $a+c$ and $b+d$ must be equal, or differ by 11?

Comment: @User58220 Yes I've seen that - The divisibility by 11 Rule. But I don't know how it can be applied here.

Comment: It may be unpleasant to get an exact count. However, this is a multiple choice question. It seems likely that the proportion of the "all digits distinct" numbers that are divisible by $11$ is not far from the proportion of numbers divisible by $11$ among all numbers from $1001$ to $9999$. And $0.091$ is the only answer supplied that is at all plausible.

Comment: It is indeed "unpleasant". But calculation, and Excel, finds that there are 4536 4-digit, "abcbd" numbers.  Excel finds that 504 of them are divisible by 11, for a ratio of 1/9.  So the correct answer appears to be 0.1111.

Comment: @User58220 Thanks. The closest to that is 0.091. There seems to be no other alternative to making that assumption. Thanks again.